# ClassNotFound error for Ignite User Defined Function in Flink Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-flink, ignite, flink-streaming

I am trying to cache the data, streamed by Apache flink, into Apache Ignite cache. I also want to run the query which uses a User Defined Function. As per Ignite, I am using `cacheConf.setSqlFunctionClasses(GetCacheKey.class)` setting while declaring the cache. The class declaration is as follows,

```
public static class GetCacheKey implements Serializable{

   @QuerySqlFunction
    public static long getCacheKey(int mac, long local) {            
        long key=(local << 5) + mac; 
        return key;
    }
```

}

When I run the code locally with Apache Flink, it works. But when I go for cluster execution of the code in Flink Cluster, I got an error that `GetCacheKey` class is not found. What will be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if GetCacheKey.class is in ignite nodes classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

The Flink directory must be available on every worker under the same path. You can use a shared NFS directory, or copy the entire Flink directory to every worker node.

Also ensure the Ignite libs are present in worker nodes classpath.